# How to change the format of an attribute in a CActiveRecord returned by a findAll method?

Tags: yii, yii-events

I have an attribute in my model that is stored in binary format inside database.
In case the attribute is a geometric( polygon ) object.

This object can be casted to several string representations.
So how can I attach an event after a find execution that allows me to change the attribute on returned set only?

My first guess was to use the onAfterFind event but it is not calling the handler with the created element as documentation suggests. My first attempt was the following in the controller.

```
// an activeRecord class
GeoTableBinaryData extends CActiveRecord {
 ... // normal active record with a table which has a binary attribute called geom
}

$model = GeoTableBinaryData::model();
$model->onAfterFind->add(
  function( CEvent $evt ){
    // get the finded object to update the geom attribute on the fly here want
    // a text representation in other case would transform it to XML or JSON
  }
);

foreach ( $model->findAll() as $geoInfo )
{
  ... // output serialized geometry
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also write getters for your different formats:

```
public function getGeoAsString()
{
    // Create the string from your DB value. For example:
    return implode(',', json_decode($this->geom));
}
```

Then you can use the `geoAsString` like a regular (read-only) attribute. You can also add a setter method, if you want to make it writeable.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way of doing this, is that in your model have a afterFind method like:

```
protected function afterFind()
{
     $this->someAttribute = $this->methodToChangeTheAttribute($this->someAttribute);
     return parent::afterFind();
}
```

and that's all, when you will use AR's methods, every found model will pass through `afterFind()` and alter the `someAttribute` as you want.

Comment: But if this the only way, what would be the purpose of Events( onAfterFind ) on Yii if you can not listen to them and react? I tried to attach an lister to afterFind to make this but the eventListener was never notified that the AR created new instances. Bug ?

Comment: You can create behaviors to attach to the afterFind() method. Also, you should look into how to properly attach an event handler, just take a look at CActiveRecordBehavior to see how it's done, or read the documentation.